# Error when drawing route between 2 BasicGeoposition in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I made an app about using map which can draw the route between 2 points in this map. However, sometime when I tried to draw a route, it returned an exception like that: "Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in map_test-main.exe
WinRT information: route". So what is the cause of this problem? Many thanks!

Heere is my code

```
try
        {
            BasicGeoposition startLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
            startLocation.Latitude = 47.643;
            startLocation.Longitude = -122.131;
            Geopoint startPoint = new Geopoint(startLocation);

            // End at the city of Seattle, Washington.
            BasicGeoposition endLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
            endLocation.Latitude = 47.604;
            endLocation.Longitude = -122.329;
            Geopoint endPoint = new Geopoint(endLocation);

            MapRouteFinderResult routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync
             (startPoint, endPoint, MapRouteOptimization.Time, MapRouteRestrictions.None);
            //MapRouteFinderResult routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync
            //   (new Geopoint(pointStart), new Geopoint(pointEnd), MapRouteOptimization.Time, MapRouteRestrictions.TollRoads);

            MapRouteView viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(routeResult.Route);

            if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
            {
                myMap.Routes.Clear();
                myMap.Routes.Add(viewOfRoute);

                await myMap.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(
                    routeResult.Route.BoundingBox, null,
                    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapAnimationKind.Default);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

P/s: By the way, I am in Vietnam when I debugged these codes.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this under the debugger - have you confirmed the `routeResult.Route` is a valid route?

Comment: OK, I fixed this, thanks :D

Comment: I am getting routeResult.status invalid credential.. can u help how did you solve your problem?